# Symfony - Propel - Determine current version of propel

Tags: symfony1, propel

Is there a better way of determining which version of Propel that Symfony 1.4 is built upon? Right now I am having to do:

```
$ -> ack -i version /path/to/symfony/lib/plugins/sfPropelPlugin/lib/vendor/
```

And as of now I am seeing this:

```
/path/to/symfony/lib/plugins/sfPropelPlugin/lib/vendor/propel-generator/default.properties
19:propel.version = 1.4.2
```

So I am assuming that Symfony v1.4.16 is using Propel version 1.4.2.

Comment: You're [right](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/tags/RELEASE_1_4_16/lib/plugins/sfPropelPlugin/lib/vendor). But you need to get it programmatically or just for information?

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to do it via the cli using something like: php symfony propel:version. Seems like it would be common sense to include a way to display the version like any other service, api we use on linux (i.e. ack -v)

Comment: Maybe you can [propose it](https://github.com/propelorm/sfPropelORMPlugin) :)

Comment: @j0K: Check the posted answer, they agreed to add it.

Comment: They do not really agreed atm :)

Comment: @j0k: Looks as though the change was merged.

Comment: @j0k: Do you use the mod? If so which SF version do use it with? Im considering using it for our SF12 project, but the devs said "it should work" vs "it will work".

Comment: It [should](http://trac.propelorm.org/browser/branches/1.3/runtime/classes/propel/Propel.php#L90) work. I'm not using propel atm. But I'm familiar with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, propel bundled with Symfony 1.x does not support the ability to determine the version, cleanly, via cli, however you can use the `ack` or `fgrep` command as I stated in OP. But if you use the `sfPropelORMPlugin` plugin, which allows you to use propel 1.6 with Symfony 1.x, they have opted to add this functionality, which I assume will be available soon. https://github.com/propelorm/sfPropelORMPlugin/pull/152